# PostgreSQL slow sql update command on Amazon EC2

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am running a PostgreSQL 9.1 server on a Amazon EC2 medium instance (with an EBS storage). I am trying to run a simple UPDATE statement on about 3 millions row. It seems to take forever.

This is the update statement:

> UPDATE "ab_device" SET "last_seen" = "ab_device"."registered_at";

The table:

```
                                   Table "public.ab_device"
    Column     |           Type           |                       Modifiers                        
---------------+--------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------
 id            | integer                  | not null default nextval('ab_device_id_seq'::regclass)
 uuid          | character varying(255)   | not null
 registered_at | timestamp with time zone | not null
 app_id        | integer                  | not null
 last_seen     | timestamp with time zone | not null
Indexes:
    "ab_tempdevice_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "ab_device_app_id_56238bcbd52372f_uniq" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (app_id, uuid)
    "ab_device_uuid" btree (uuid)
    "ab_tempdevice_app_id" btree (app_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "app_id_refs_id_9cb306ef" FOREIGN KEY (app_id) REFERENCES ab_app(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
Referenced by:
    TABLE "ab_trial" CONSTRAINT "device_id_refs_id_050eed1f" FOREIGN KEY (device_id) REFERENCES ab_device(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

The "explain" of the request:

```
                                QUERY PLAN                                
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Update on ab_device  (cost=0.00..78210.65 rows=2761865 width=59)
   ->  Seq Scan on ab_device  (cost=0.00..78210.65 rows=2761865 width=59)
(2 rows)
```

The CPU iowait is high when I run the request. Is it normal that the request takes a lot of time? Is it because of the I/O of the machine are poor?

Thank you for your insight.

Comment: A performance of IO on Amazon is usually terrible - mainly for longer tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this could be because of Postgresql's MVCC implementation. It makes this kind of single updates expensive. In these cases, each row needs to be copied as a new version, and the old version will be marked as deleted.

If you can, change some parameters before the update and do a VACUUM FULL to force table rewrite. Refer to: [Slow simple update query on PostgreSQL database with 3 million rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361291/slow-simple-update-query-on-postgresql-database-with-3-million-rows) for more info.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am not sure about the other post you refer. It's not completely clear for me about what to do. It talks about HOT but does not show how to use it.

Comment: You should try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3100232/362298. The HOT update is done automatically by postgres depending on the indexes and type of update. You can check whether it was hot updated by issuing the command: `pg_stat_user_tables.n_tup_hot_upd`. Also, refer to source docs for details, if you are interested: http://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=src/backend/access/heap/README.HOT;hb=HEAD