# Postgres. UPDATE for one record takes long time

Tags: sql, postgresql

it's my update -

```
UPDATE "users" SET "name" = $?, "is_read" = $?, "updated_at" = $? WHERE "users"."id" = ?
```

and **sometimes** it takes about 150 seconds(but in normaly - it's fast). Could you please advise me possible reasons? users.id have index

Comment: Any triggers? Is users.id indexed?

Comment: yes, users.id indexed. if I have view with this table - it can be reason?

Comment: Views shouldn't make any difference. Index re-build can perhaps make some difference, but I don't know postgresql that well... Triggers can make huge difference.

Comment: This might help (HOT updates) http://stackoverflow.com/a/3100232/3574819

Comment: Look at `select * from pg_stat_activity`. Maybe some query lock the table?

Answer (score 0):

To speed this update, you want an index on `users(id)`:

```
create index idx_users_id on users(id)
```

Normally, the `id` would be declared as a primary key (or at least unique) and already have an index.  But if it isn't, this should help.

Note:  There are other possibilities, such as other processes having a lock on the table or very complex insert triggers.

Comment: Thank you, index on users(id) exist. What about views with users table? it can be reason?

Comment: @ArtoymP . . . Views can also have a negative impact on performance.